# A practical way to approach maintaining code bundles in git

Tags: git

I am working on a project where we have multiple plugins that inherit from a common base plugin. We are trying to figure out a way to use git in a practical way to do this.

```
Example Repo:
    OfficePlugin [directory containing several .cs files and a .csproj]
    CopyPlugin [directory with .cs files and .csproj. Class inherits from OfficePlugins]
    CutPlugin [directory with .cs files and .csproj. Class inherits from OfficePlugins]
    PastePlugin [directory with .cs files and .csproj. Class inherits from OfficePlugins]
    FontPlugin [directory with .cs files and .csproj. Class inherits from OfficePlugins]
    DecorationsPlugin [directory with .cs files and .csproj. Class inherits from OfficePlugins]
```

Ok, so for this example we have the base project called OfficePlugin in this case. (C# projects contain several files bundled together, but this could be a question for any language.)

Let's pretend we have 3 programmers working on projects.

```
Mark (Our I/O guy):
    CopyPlugin
    CutPlugin
    PastePlugin
Nancy (Out Font manager):
    FontPlugin
    FontDecorationsPlugin
Joe (The cross department integrator):
    FontDecorationsPlugin
    PastePlugin
```

Under a normal git setup with all these files in one repo (from what I know), our programmers would have to ignore the directories that they don't control. That's fine, no problems with that.

However, let's say that Joe added the ability to do a special type of paste where font styling is preserved when you paste the text from one document to another. Followed by a few commits.

```
Commit Log
    Commit: 12345  Author: Mark   CopyPlugin Enhancements
    Commit: 23456  Author: Nancy  FontPlugin Speed Profiling
    Commit: 34567  Author: Joe    PastePlugin Font Decoration Ability
    Commit: ABCDE  Author: Mark   Update of all I/O Plugins
```

At this point, Mark and Joe realize that Joe's change was a breaking change. The PastePlugin's directory needs to be rolled back to commit ABCDE, but changes on the FontPlugin and CopyPlugin don't want to be lost.

I have a similar situation except that we have closer to 150 plugins. 150 repos (one for each plugin) seems crazy and I would need a copy of OfficePlugin in each.

SubModule or SubRepo looks like it might be a good option, but not sure automatic building with Bamboo would work when adding or removing additional repos.

Could do some crazy branch scheme and merging, but that sounds really painful. Another option would be to find that exact commit and checkout every file in that directory. That option seems cumbersome, especially if we need to go 2 commits back and dig through the log to see where that could have been 3 months ago.

Another option could be tagging somehow? But I think that would be as challenging as checking out a specific directory.

Is there a practical way to handle this situation?

Comment: IMO git submodules should be avoided. It's behavior is not clear to me. If you `git pull` on the main project submodules aren't always updated. Isn't there some dependency management system where you could package each plugin seperately and depend on a specific version? NuGet or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use a single repo with a good path structure.

To rollback just this one plugin in your example is pretty easy:

```
cd PastePlugin
git checkout ABCDE -- .
git commit
```

That's it.

Read up on how Google structure their git repository (emphasis on *y*) as inspiration, though their approach is a result of many, many years of work. But the lesson to learn is that it is very well possible to have many projects in a single repository, and that a lot can be achieved with tooling  (i.e. scripts, hooks...)